# Arguments against testbackdoor pattern

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing

I will give a short company internal lecture on testing. Could you please provide me some nice example why the so called testbackdoor pattern is considered as a devil?
I am sure it is an anti-pattern but I would like to point this out for the colleagues too.

I have a feeling that testbackdoor can cause headache, however I cannot really describe why it is so.

Comment: What's that have never heard of it? Can you elaborate on it?

Comment: I found this link which gives detail description on it http://xunitpatterns.com/Back%20Door%20Manipulation.html

Answer (score 0):

[Back Door Manipulation](http://xunitpatterns.com/Back%20Door%20Manipulation.html) creates a coupling between your test and the fixture used by the [SUT](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html), which means that if the implementation of the fixture changes, then you might also need to update your test. However when you refactor your SUT, the test is supposed to allow you to confirm that the refactoring has not changed the behaviour of the SUT. You can't do this if the refactoring changed the fixture in a way which requires you to change the test.

For instance, just say you're testing a class that maintains state in private fields and you used back door manipulation to modify those fields for setup and check the value of the fields for verification. The class is then refactored (for example) to remove some redundancy in the fields and use more appropriate types in the fields. Your test is now broken and you have no way of ensuring that the behavior of the class has not changed. You can change your test to use the new fields, but how do you know for certain that the test is still testing the same behaviour and that you haven't introduced a bug in your SUT and your test?

Answer (score 0):

When used in a unit test, the Back Door Manipulation pattern enables and encourages continued reliance on external dependencies.  It enables violations of the Dependency Inversion principle.  This permits dangerous practices, such as global variables.  And it couples your testing and development efforts to an external database.

### What is a *unit* test?

A unit test is a test that tests one unit of your *code*, not a function of your system.  It's testing one path through a method.  It shouldn't be trying to test databases. It shouldn't be trying to test other functions of your code.  It should be only testing the small amount of code you see on the screen.

### Globals are bad.

Think about what global variables are, and why they are such a problem.  They're hidden pieces of state that you rely on that someone else can change.  If someone changes that value anywhere else in your program, your code will act differently.  Because a global is not visible on your interface, someone who wants to reuse your code won't know the significance of the global.  Globals violate encapsulation, so your code is non-modular.  Globals make code hard to understand, hard to reuse, hard to test, and cause bugs.

Using Back Door Manipulation, you could still write a unit test that sets the global, runs the test, then checks the global.  The test enables the continued existence of the global.  But the test isn't really proving anything about your code, because any other piece of code could change the global at any time.  Instead, the code should be refactored to have the variable passed in on the interface, following the Dependency Injection pattern.  That way whoever is trying to reuse your code will know they have to provide that piece of data.  There is nothing hidden from the person trying to reuse your code.

### Databases are bigger than a unit.

Think about why dependence on databases is bad for unit testing.  The test system needs to have the database available in order to run the test.  The developers need to have the database available in order to run their tests and develop.  The network to the database has to be up.  The database server has to have the right databases, the right schema, the right users, the right stored procedures, the right tables, the right rows, and the right values present.  The user and the test server have to have valid credentials and passwords to access the network, the server, and the database.  The developer's database and the test database have to both speak the same dialect of SQL.  The tests require write access in order to set up the test, even if the application's access needs to be read-only.  Tests on a shared database can be interfered with by other people using the database and modifying the contents.  The developer's workstation and the test server has to have the correct data access objects installed.  And if any one of those is a problem, testing stops and test driven development stops.

None of those dependencies prove anything about the working of the code or of the production environment. So they're expensive to set up and maintain, they add nothing to the proof that the actual code is being tested, they can bring coding to a halt, and availability is always required for all testing and development.

Instead, the code should use dependency injection to pass in the database connection (or the needed data, or whatever).  The unit test harness can inject a fake or mock database connection, one which will return exactly the data needed to establish the test conditions.  When written properly, the automated unit test system will run perfectly with no access to a database.  As a bonus, with no waiting on database access the tests will run orders of magnitude faster when getting data from mock objects.  That's important when you have 50,000 unit tests to run each build.

### When is Back Door Manipulation appropriate?

The ideas of Back Door Manipulation are great for automated system testing and automated integration testing.  They can prove that a user-level function works in the presence of the correct data.  They can prove that a user-level function manipulates the data in the database appropriately.

Back Door Manipulation is often the most effective way to write a unit test for legacy code.  Legacy code is code that has no unit tests, and is a reality for a lot of existing projects.  Back Door Manipulation can help a developer write a test to assure the continued stability of the legacy code, even in the presence of ongoing modifications.  It may not be good code that is being preserved, but it's code you still have to live with for some time.

But when done inside a unit test during test driven development of new code, using Back Door Manipulation encourages a test larger than a unit test.  It's bad for automated unit testing because it can bring test driven development to a halt.  And it's bad for code quality and reuse, because it enables non-modular code.